# Primefaces password match on blur always validation error

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, passwords, blur

Using primefaces password tag, I want to use the match as shown in the show case but with on blur validation, I use the following code:

```
<h:form id="formulaire">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />

    ...

    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{registrationBean.user.password}"
        size="47" label="Password" required="true"
        placeholder="Password*" >
        <f:validateLength minimum="6" />
        <p:ajax event="blur"/>
    </p:password>
    <br />
    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{registrationBean.user.password}"
        size="47" label="Verification" required="true"
        placeholder="Verification*" match="pwd1">
        <p:ajax event="blur"/>
    </p:password>
    <br/>
    <p:commandButton action="#{registrationBean.register}" value="register"/>


</h:form>
```

I use the match on the verification, to avoid displaying the error message 
before trying to reproduce it. 
the problem is that growl always displays the error message.
Even when I put the match on the first field, the growl error keeps showing.
Thank you for your help.

Edit:

The Best solution I managed to get is the following:

```
<p:password id="pwd1" value="#{registrationBean.password}"
    size="47" label="Password" required="true"
    placeholder="Password*" match="pwd2">
    <f:validateLength minimum="6" />
</p:password>
<br />
<p:password id="pwd2" value="#{registrationBean.password}"
    size="47" label="Verification" required="true"
    placeholder="Verification*" >
    <p:ajax process="pwd1 pwd2" event="blur"/>
</p:password>
```

the draw back is that there is no ajax verification after password is entered (length...), this is done only once the verification is entered.
(still looking for a better solution)

Comment: Also tried this:
<p:ajax process="pwd1 pwd2" update="pwd1 pwd2" event="blur"/>